# Iterating through list of items, show allocated image on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to display a list of names and its allocated images.

Therefore I've created a service containing all the name and their images (ignore link):

```
import { Case } from './case';

export const CASES: Case[] = [
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'WeWork Berlin', image: '/assets/images/berlin.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Fritzhansen', image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Savum', image: '/assets/images/savum.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Eskay', image: '/assets/images/eskay.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Diesel', image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Mobilia', image: '/assets/images/mobilia.png', link: '' },
  { name: 'Rarekind', image: '/assets/images/rarekind.png', link: '' }
];
```

This list of cases is fetched inside of the case-list component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CASES } from '../mock/mock-cases';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-case-list',
  templateUrl: './case-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./case-list.component.scss']
})
export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

  cases = CASES;

  ...

}
```

In the case-list's html file, I'm iterating through this array to display the names and their images:

```
<div *ngFor="let case of cases" class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">

  <ul>
    <li class="text-center">
      {{ case.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <img src="{{ case.image }}" alt="First" class="position-absolute align-self-center d-none">

</div>
```

It works, but I want it to function a little different. Currently all images are being displayed.

**But I want the image to solely be visible, when the associated `li` item is being hovered.** Additionally only the image allocated to the `li` item (which is hovered) shall be displayed - f.e. if `li` Savum is being hovered, only its image `savum.png` shall be displayed.

**How can I realize this behavior in Angular?**

Comment: Simply add a property `activeCase` to your component and use `(onmouseover)="activeCase=case` and onmouseleafe in your li tag. Not tested, that's why I add it as a comment.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Would you be so nice to illustrate your suggestion in an answer - I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make two functions for mouseenter and mouseleave, so that we can set the image url when you hover the particular list item. mouseenter function used to get the url of the particular item by passing as a parameter and stored it into a public property imageUrl.

And you .ts file should be like this.

```
    export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

      cases = CASES;

      imageUrl: string;

      mouseEnter(url: string) {
        this.imageUrl = url;
      }

      mouseLeave() {
        this.imageUrl = null;
      }

    }

// And then use that value to update the src attribute of the image tag and make a note only it contains a string it will be displayed and i am not going to do the validation because its not important in this case.
```

.html would be like this

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">

  <ul>
    <li (mouseenter)="mouseEnter(case.image)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()" class="text-center" *ngFor="let case of cases">
      {{ case.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <img *ngIf="!!imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl" class="position-absolute align-self-center">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

1. Assign `css class` to each `li` and `img` based on their index. By default each image is hidden.
2. Register `mouseenter and mouseleave` event on each `li`  like below :

   ```
     <ul>
       <li class="text-center" *ngFor="let case of cases,let i=index" 
           (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter(i) "  
           (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave(i)" >
         {{ case.name }}
       </li>
     </ul>

     <img *ngFor="let case of cases, let i=index" src="{{ case.image }}" alt="First" class="position-absolute align-self-center icon-image" ngClass="imgss{{i}}">
   </div>
   ```

the css of `.icon-image` class :

```
  .icon-image{
  display: none;
}
```

3. Capture the events in your  `ts` file . and based on the index of the element being hovered, change the visibility of the element.

`

```
mouseEnter(itemIndex){
 console.log('hover over' ,itemIndex);
 const element =  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`.imgss${itemIndex}`);
 element.style.display ="block";
 console.log('hover over' ,element);

}
mouseLeave(itemIndex){
 const element =  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`.imgss${itemIndex}`);
  element.style.display ="none";
}
```

`
Working example :

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5aj5np)